# tkinter blanks bottom of a canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to put objects in a canvas under tkinter [8.6] with python 3.  Everything more than 256 pixels below the upper left corner is blank.  Can't figure out why. Here is a stripped down code showing what I mean:

*Python 3.7*

```
from tkinter import *

class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Canvas Test")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack(fill=BOTH)
        CornerLeft = 230
        CornerUpper = 30
        Fullythere = 256
        ChoppedBottom = 257
        canvas.create_rectangle(CornerUpper, CornerLeft, 400, ChoppedBottom)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = Test(root)
    root.geometry("600x900")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set background color for `root` (ie. `green`) and `Test` frame (ie. `red`)

```
class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        self['bg'] = 'red'

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root['bg'] = 'green'
```

then you will see that it doesn't use full window

[image]

If you set `expand=True` for `Test` frame

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

then you will see that `Test` uses full window but `Canvas` still not uses full window

[image]

If you also use  `expand=True` for `Canvas`

```
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```

then you will see that it uses full window and you can see draws below 256

[image]

---

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__()
        #self['bg'] = 'red'

        self.master.title("Canvas Test")
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        corner_left = 30
        corner_upper = 230
        corner_right = corner_left + 400
        corner_bottom = corner_upper + 500
        canvas.create_rectangle(corner_left, corner_upper, corner_right, corner_bottom)

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    #root['bg'] = 'green'

    ex = Test(root)
    root.geometry("600x900")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a perfect answer, very clear and everything I need to fix my code.